# iSCSI targets don't appear after rescan

Tags: vmware-esx, iscsi

I have an Equallogic 4000PS SAN box to which I have connected 2 x ESX 4.0.0 hosts sharing the LUNs. I have an older ESX 3.5 host which I want to setup to share the same LUNs. I have setup a vmkernel port with 2 NICs attached to 2 the iSCSI switch. When I perform an iSCSI software adapter rescan, it takes a long time and it doesn't find the targets. In the ESX-3.5 host's log file I find these messages:

```
Mar 30 08:52:48 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:23:11.394 cpu5:1039)WARNING: SCSI: 279: SCSI device type 0xd is not supported. Cannot create target vmhba1:288:0  
Mar 30 08:52:48 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:23:11.394 cpu5:1039)WARNING: SCSI: 1293: LegacyMP Plugin could not claim path: vmhba1:288:0. Not supported  
Mar 30 08:52:48 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:23:11.394 cpu5:1039)WARNING: ScsiPath: 3187: Plugin 'legacyMP' had an error (Not supported) while claiming path 'vmhba1:C0:T288:L0'.Skipping the path.  
Mar 30 08:52:48 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:23:11.397 cpu0:1040)WARNING: SCSI: 279: SCSI device type 0xd is not supported. Cannot create target vmhba1:288:0  
Mar 30 08:52:48 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:23:11.397 cpu0:1040)WARNING: SCSI: 1293: LegacyMP Plugin could not claim path: vmhba1:288:0. Not supported  
Mar 30 08:52:48 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:23:11.397 cpu0:1040)WARNING: ScsiPath: 3187: Plugin 'legacyMP' had an error (Not supported) while claiming path 'vmhba1:C0:T288:L0'.Skipping the path.    
Mar 30 08:52:48 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:23:11.442 cpu1:1040)WARNING: SCSI: 279: SCSI device type 0xd is not supported. Cannot create target vmhba1:288:0  
Mar 30 08:52:48 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:23:11.442 cpu1:1040)WARNING: SCSI: 1293: LegacyMP Plugin could not claim path: vmhba1:288:0. Not supported  
Mar 30 08:52:48 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:23:11.442 cpu1:1040)WARNING: ScsiPath: 3187: Plugin 'legacyMP' had an error (Not supported) while claiming path 'vmhba1:C0:T288:L0'.Skipping the path.  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:32.874 cpu3:1040)WARNING: SCSI: 279: SCSI device type 0xd is not supported. Cannot create target vmhba1:288:0  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:32.874 cpu3:1040)WARNING: SCSI: 1293: LegacyMP Plugin could not claim path: vmhba1:288:0. Not supported  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:32.874 cpu3:1040)WARNING: ScsiPath: 3187: Plugin 'legacyMP' had an error (Not supported) while claiming path 'vmhba1:C0:T288:L0'.Skipping the path.  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:32.884 cpu4:1041)WARNING: SCSI: 279: SCSI device type 0xd is not supported. Cannot create target vmhba1:288:0  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:32.884 cpu4:1041)WARNING: SCSI: 1293: LegacyMP Plugin could not claim path: vmhba1:288:0. Not supported  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:32.884 cpu4:1041)WARNING: ScsiPath: 3187: Plugin 'legacyMP' had an error (Not supported) while claiming path 'vmhba1:C0:T288:L0'.Skipping the path.  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:32.888 cpu3:1040)WARNING: SCSI: 279: SCSI device type 0xd is not supported. Cannot create target vmhba1:288:0  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:32.888 cpu3:1040)WARNING: SCSI: 1293: LegacyMP Plugin could not claim path: vmhba1:288:0. Not supported  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:32.888 cpu3:1040)WARNING: ScsiPath: 3187: Plugin 'legacyMP' had an error (Not supported) while claiming path 'vmhba1:C0:T288:L0'.Skipping the path.  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.042 cpu7:1039)WARNING: SCSI: 279: SCSI device type 0xd is not supported. Cannot create target vmhba1:288:0  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.042 cpu7:1039)WARNING: SCSI: 1293: LegacyMP Plugin could not claim path: vmhba1:288:0. Not supported  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.042 cpu7:1039)WARNING: ScsiPath: 3187: Plugin 'legacyMP' had an error (Not supported) while claiming path 'vmhba1:C0:T288:L0'.Skipping the path.  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.044 cpu3:1040)WARNING: SCSI: 279: SCSI device type 0xd is not supported. Cannot create target vmhba1:288:0  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.044 cpu3:1040)WARNING: SCSI: 1293: LegacyMP Plugin could not claim path: vmhba1:288:0. Not supported  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.044 cpu3:1040)WARNING: ScsiPath: 3187: Plugin 'legacyMP' had an error (Not supported) while claiming path 'vmhba1:C0:T288:L0'.Skipping the path.   
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.045 cpu4:1041)WARNING: SCSI: 279: SCSI device type 0xd is not supported. Cannot create target vmhba1:288:0  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.045 cpu4:1041)WARNING: SCSI: 1293: LegacyMP Plugin could not claim path: vmhba1:288:0. Not supported  
Mar 30 08:57:09 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.045 cpu4:1041)WARNING: ScsiPath: 3187: Plugin 'legacyMP' had an error (Not supported) while claiming path 'vmhba1:C0:T288:L0'.Skipping the path.  
Mar 30 08:57:10 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.308 cpu3:1040)WARNING: SCSI: 279: SCSI device type 0xd is not supported. Cannot create target vmhba1:288:0  
Mar 30 08:57:10 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.309 cpu3:1040)WARNING: SCSI: 1293: LegacyMP Plugin could not claim path: vmhba1:288:0. Not supported  
Mar 30 08:57:10 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.309 cpu3:1040)WARNING: ScsiPath: 3187: Plugin 'legacyMP' had an error (Not supported) while claiming path 'vmhba1:C0:T288:L0'.Skipping the path.  
Mar 30 08:57:10 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.598 cpu2:1040)WARNING: SCSI: 279: SCSI device type 0xd is not supported. Cannot create target vmhba1:288:0  
Mar 30 08:57:10 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.598 cpu2:1040)WARNING: SCSI: 1293: LegacyMP Plugin could not claim path: vmhba1:288:0. Not supported  
Mar 30 08:57:10 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.598 cpu2:1040)WARNING: ScsiPath: 3187: Plugin 'legacyMP' had an error (Not supported) while claiming path 'vmhba1:C0:T288:L0'.Skipping the path.  
Mar 30 08:57:10 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.600 cpu7:1039)WARNING: SCSI: 279: SCSI device type 0xd is not supported. Cannot create target vmhba1:288:0  
Mar 30 08:57:10 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.600 cpu7:1039)WARNING: SCSI: 1293: LegacyMP Plugin could not claim path: vmhba1:288:0. Not supported  
Mar 30 08:57:10 sc59 vmkernel: 368:19:27:33.600 cpu7:1039)WARNING: ScsiPath: 3187: Plugin 'legacyMP' had an error (Not supported) while claiming path 'vmhba1:C0:T288:L0'.Skipping the path.
```

Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

Those errors refer to vmhba1 which is not the iSCSI Software initiator, that will be something like vmhba32 or higher. The particular errors you are seeing are likely to be [related to this VMware kb article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1005846) they refer to a path to a storage volume that cannot be used for VMFS partitions. These errors can be safely ignored.

As to your specific problem my guess is that you haven't added a Service Console port on the 3.5 host to the iSCSI network. With ESX 4 the Service Console connection is not required but it was necessary under ESX 3.5. You can check connectivity between the host and your array by using vmkping (to test the iSCSI vmKernel port can reach the arrays ports) and ping (to test that the Service Console can reach the array's ports).

It is possible that you haven't correctly modified the access controls on the Equallogic Volumes to grant access to them from the new initiator but seeing as you have two working ESX 4 hosts that can see the volume(s) I think this is far less likely.